# 401 Unauthorized http://localhost:8080/manager/html

Tags: tomcat7, war, http-status-code-401

Hello I am beginner with Tomcat7.

I added following code /etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml

```
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<user roles="manager-gui,admin-guit" password="admin" username="admin"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

but still I am not able to access "manager-webapp"

tried crediantials username: admin, password: admin.

But not able to access it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: <tomcat-users>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<user roles="manager-gui,admin-guit" password="admin" username="admin"/>
</tomcat-users>

Comment: `manager-script` is there? in your xml @user2781186

Comment: No There is no manager-script

Answer (score 0):

it will be helpful to you

```
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>     
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="admin-script"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-status,admin-gui,admin-script" />
```

Once you add this above script and restart the server

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: It promts for username, password again , and on cancel it shows 401 error

Comment: on `LoginOk ` can u able to access Manager apps

Comment: there's no default script in on `Cancel` so it will show 401 error @user2781186

Comment: No, I am not able to login, On Clicking on Ok it still shows promt for username password

Comment: did you added above script in `tomcat-users.xml`

Comment: and how did you restart the tomcat server?

Comment: I used sudo service tomcat7 restart to restart, And Yes I added roles in tomcat-users.xml

Comment: restart the system  and check again

Comment: Okay will check.

Comment: Actually I am trying to deploy an war file on ubuntu server 14.04, tried restarting apache server. But not working,

Comment: are you using OpenJDK  or  Oracle?

Comment: OpenJDK - java version "1.7.0_151"